# how to get plus code by using latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift4

I am new to google maps.My requirement, I have to get plus code using latitude and longitude of user.I am able to get latitude and longitude.But after that how to get plus code.I am not aware of that.If any one helps out todo this ,Would be very great.Thanks in advance.

```
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!

            lat = locValue.latitude
            long = locValue.longitude
            str1 = String(lat)
            str2 = String(long)
        }
        func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
         actobj.stopAnimating()

            if let error = error {
                locationtxt.text = "Unable to Find Address for Location"

            } else {
                if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                    locationtxt.text = placemark.compactAddress
                    actobj.isHidden=true
                } else {
                    locationtxt.text = "No Matching Addresses Found"
                }
            }
        }
 @IBAction func locationbtn(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let latAsString: String = str1, let lat = Double(latAsString) else { return }
        guard let lngAsString: String = str2, let lng = Double(lngAsString) else { return }

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)

        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in

            self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
        }

        actobj.isHidden = false
        actobj.startAnimating()
    }

        }

    extension CLPlacemark {

        var compactAddress: String? {
            if let name = name {
                var result = name

                if let street = thoroughfare {
                    result += ", \(street)"
                }

                if let city = locality {
                    result += ", \(city)"
                }
                if let country = country {
                    result += ", \(country)"
                }
                return result
            }
            return nil
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is this "plus code"?

Comment: are you talking about dial code like (+91 , +971 etc)??

Comment: Would come in Handy : https://github.com/google/open-location-code/wiki/Plus-codes-API

Comment: not dial code.https://plus.codes/

Comment: Please go through that link,and search with any address then it will redirect to google maps .there you can see the pluscode of that perticular location

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get this way easily

```
        let lat = "19.0760"
        let long = "72.8777"
        let email = "abc@test.com"
        let ApiURL = "https://plus.codes/api?address=\(lat),\(long)&email=\(email)"

        Alamofire.request(ApiURL).responseJSON { response in
            print("Result: \(response.result)")
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)")
            }
            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Possibility is to use [Google Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-details) and consume [GMSPlace](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_plus_code) class. It contains plusCode property. Here a challenge could be to get GMSPlace object from coordinates which you can cover using [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) which has an option to take coordinate as params and provide us with `place_id` in response which can be [handed over to Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client#a759a5c382414ccce696eca38f22b3c1b).

Answer (score 0):

A second possibility is using [this web service](https://bitbucket.org/hd1/jpassword/raw/master/src/test/java/us/d8u/balance/Tests.java) -- test code linked. What you'd like to do is given under plusEncodingLatLonWorks(). If Java is a foreign language to your good self, read on.

Http post to https://hd1-units.herokuapp.com/plus with the JSON body '{"latitude": 0, "longitude": 0}' and a content-type header being 'application/json'. The plus code will be in the return json's plusCode key.